# How to access set of resource files within a JAR in JAvaagent

Tags: java, jar, log4j, javaagents

I implemented a `javaagent` and need to access some resource files within the agent's jar file. (eg: `log4j.properties` file, keystore `.jks` file etc.) If I put them in the resource folder under src/main they get included in the agent jar.

> Agent JAR
>
> - log4j.properties
> - META-INF
> - agentFolder

But how can I access those files during run time of the agent? How can I give the path to those files within agent's project files. Little explanation would be highly appreciated. If it is not possible I would like to have some suggestions on how to access those configuration file more effectively. Since the agent will be running on different products, I though that giving a folder structure would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A Java agent is just another Java program. The jar file containing your agent ends up on the class path and can therefore be accessed just like any other resource. For example, try `MyAgent.class.getResource("/log4j.properties")` to get hold of such a file. This should work as expected in any Java program and work on any platform.

Comment: I have tried it by adding the properties file to resources folder. But it prints logs only for the class with premain method. In MyClassFileTransformer it says no appenders can be found. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: Of course you can. But your question was about how to access these ressources. The answer is: As if you put the agent jar on the class path.

Comment: But when I add only the log4j properties file to resources it prints logs only for the class with premain method. In MyClassFileTransformer it says no appenders can be found. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: Are you registering your `ClassFileTransformer` from another place in your application that the `premain` method? Maybe the system class loader is not visible to that other code's class loader.

Comment: I am just using the `addTransformer()` in the class which contain premain and the class which implements ClassFileTransformer is in another class. Since I am using org.apache.commons.logging, if I add commons-logging.properties file then it work for that also. But is it correct?

Comment: As long as you have the agent active, yes. The question is where you want the file to live. In your setup, the application would break if you do not use the agent.